If loop with two conditions
I want to delete all pdf files in a directory, except for two with file names defined as the variables exception1 and exception2.
chcp 65001
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set pathname=%~p1
set letter=%~d1
pushd %letter%%pathname%
chcp
set exception1="218-0553.2.pdf"
set exception2="218-0553.2 test.pdf"
pause

dir *.pdf
for %%f in (*.pdf) do (
    if /i not "%%~nxf"=="%exception1%" (
        if /i not "%%~nxf"=="%exception2%" (
            echo Deleting "%%f"
            del "%%f"
        ) else (
            echo Keeping "%%f"
        )
    ) else (
        echo Keeping "%%f"
    )
)
popd
endlocal

This generates an error message:
else was unexpected at this time

I've also tried this, which doesn't work either:
if /i not "%%~nxf"=="%exception1%" and not "%%~nxf"=="%exception2%"

Is there something Im missing?

The problem is that you are defining variables incorrectly. Please always use the recommended syntax Set "VariableName=ExpandedValue". So in the case above change lines 3, 4, 5, 7 & 8 to set "pathname=%~p1", set "letter=%~d1", pushd "%letter%%pathname%", set "exception1=218-0553.2.pdf" & set "exception2=218-0553.2 test.pdf" respectively. Then consider removing lines 3 & 4, and change line 5 to pushd "%~dp1".

You are double quoting the exception filenames.
First you have this:
set exception1="218-0553.2.pdf"
set exception2="218-0553.2 test.pdf"

and later
if /i not "%%~nxf"=="%exception1%" (

which will evaluate to
if /i not "%%~nxf"==""218-0553.2.pdf"" (

So changing the exception values to
set exception1=218-0553.2.pdf
set exception2=218-0553.2 test.pdf

will fix it.

That did solve the problem. Quoting in batch files does my head in sometimes.

@KJ Interesting, I've never seen this syntax before, is it documented somewhere?

The idea of the quotes is to protect against poison characters, (most commonly with filenames, ampersands e.g. set var=alpha & numeric.ext. Where "%var%" would expand to "alpha " and the invalid command numeric would generate an error message). The only spaces issue is with accidental inclusion of trailing space characters, whereby "%var%" could be defined with an unexpected expansion of "value ". Obviously if the accidental inclusion is not noticed, "218-0553.2.pdf" would never match "218-0553.2.pdf ".

@KJ Hm set "x=a&b" and then echo %x% still gives that error, so the problem is just moved elsewhere it seems

Of course @Berend, because echo a&b would display a and try to run the command or utility named b, reporting back accordingly. That however is about using the echo command, and completely unrelated to the definition of variables.

@Berend And the simplest way to solve this problem is use Delayed Expansion: set "x=a&b" and then echo !x!

Have you tried this?
@echo off
set "exception1=file1.pdf"
set "exception2=file2.pdf"

for %%f in (*.pdf) do (
    if /i not "%%~nxf"=="%exception1%" if /i not "%%~nxf"=="%exception2%" (
        echo Deleting "%%f"
        REM del "%%f"
    ) else (
        echo Keeping "%%f"
    )
)

as far as i know and i am not the best scripter by far. In Batch each if statement needs its else on the same line or enclosed properly to avoid syntax issues. Also what I did here is instead of using nested If Statements, combining both into one since I always found this approach far easier and more readable. Also the line echo Deleting "%%f gives you feedback what got deleted. If you don't want this simply comment the line. the /i makes the comparison case-sensetive

You could improve your answer by explaining what is different in your script, and why this would fix the problem

was already on it. clicked quicker than i thought

It doesn't really look like a bash script though

I tried that too, but got a message 'else was unexpected at this time.'

@Berend my god you are right... guess i have to shut down my pc and end my shift. Its Batch not Bash my brain is way too mush to give proper answer. if this case keeps open i retry another way after a good night of sleep

@Hobbes, this answer actually does solve your stated issue. The problem is you chose to copy only some of it, rather than the important part, (the solution), which is lines 2 and 3. It shows you the correct and recommended syntax for the set command, and did so well before the answer you have selected as accepted!

Both answers were changed, and I changed my answer as well, so who wrote what when is not an easy question to answer.  I went with the answer that identified the problem.

No code was changed in the two edits to date @Hobbes. The original variables defined on lines 2 & 3 were submitted exactly as they currently appear.

As I said, I went with the answer that didn't just gave me working code, it explained what was wrong with my code.

You are free to choose whichever answer you prefer. That however was not the reason for my comment. My comment was because yours, "I tried that too, but got a message 'else was unexpected at this time.'", implied that the answer posted above was somehow not a solution, and produced that same error as your own code. That is not true and the code above is a working solution for your task. The person who posted this answer, does not deserve being wronged and unrewarded, for being first to fix it!

This post contained an if statement "if /i not "%%~nxf"=="%exception1%" if /i not "%%~nxf"=="%exception2%" " and I had tried that exact if statement minutes before, as noted in my question. The error message seems to be about the if statement, not the variable definition that happened before it so yes, I dismissed this answer. If I had noticed the change in variable definition I may have gotten working code but I would not have know why it worked. The other answer actually explained what the problem was.

Guys it's not that deep while I appreciate @Compo for appreciating my code I really do not care who gets the award and who not. I come here on SO see problem -> might have a fix for it and just share what i know. The rest is irrelevant as long as OP gets things working

This is interesting... You wrote: "In Batch each if statement needs its else..." that is true. However, in your code you put two if statements but just one else! There is no way to "combining both IF's into one" in Batch files as you wrote. As result, in your code the else belongs to the second if and the first if have not any else.

@Aacini thats only partly true. I have to strongly disagree with your satement of no way to "combining both IF's into one" because what I did in my script is called chaining conditions. Only if both "if"s are correct the statement will execute since i properly declared the brackets. I can recommend a good source https://ss64.com/nt/if.html under there you will find the section "Chaining IF commands (AND)" really great stuff for scripting

The "Chaining IF commands (AND)" source you linked mentions nothing about "combining IF's" and show two separate IF commands indeed... In your code, if the file is file2.pdf the echo Keeping "file2.pdf" is executed because it is placed in the else that belongs to the second if. However, if the file is file1.pdf then nothing is shown! If both IF's could be "combined" in the way you claim, the only else should work for both cases, but this is not true. Run a test if you don't belive me! Your belive could lead to errors in a program that have nested several IF's and ELSE's

@LMA  Have you already convinced yourself that your belive is wrong? If not, I invite you to read this answer where the poster clearly say: "the else applies only to the last if, not to the ANDing of the two conditions..."

I suggest you to use this method instead that works correctly no matters the number of files:
@echo off
chcp 65001
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set "pathname=%~P1"
set "letter=%~D1"
pushd "%letter%%pathname%"
chcp
set "exception=|218-0553.2.pdf|218-0553.2 test.pdf|"
pause

dir *.pdf
for %%f in (*.pdf) do (
    if "!exception:|%%~NXf|=!" == "%exception%" (
        echo Deleting "%%f"
        del "%%f"
    ) else (
        echo Keeping "%%f"
    )
)
popd
endlocal

The "!exception:|%%~NXf|=!" replacement tries to delete the current file name from the list of files. If the result is the same than the original list, then the current file is not in the list, so it is deleted.
This code also shows the correct and standard use of quotes to enclose filenames that may include spaces, and not include the quotes themselves in the variable value.

I love the including of chcp 65001 for non ASCII filenames. really adding more scalability to it.

@LMA Such a "feature" appears in the original code... Perhaps you didn't noticed it...

indeed i missed that line
